# How To Properly Show/Hide UI Controls & Handle Constraints

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I'm building a realtime IOS dashboard and I need to dynamically display UI elements (currently a UISlider or UISwitch) inside a UITableViewCell depending on the data retrieved.  The tableview cell (and associated XIB) has a label on the left side and either a UISwitch or UISlider on the right.

I'm able to show/hide the UI elements via the isHidden property of each component but the autolayout constraint always places the UI elements next to each other even though in the interface builder I placed the UI components on top of each other (because I need to show either the slider or switch not both).  BTW - I can't use multiple UITableViewCells due to some RXSwift issues.

Comment: please include a screenshot of the xib file

Answer (score 0):

The 'hidden' property will not change auto layout constraints.
The control will be hidden but will still take up the space it's meant to take.
Having said that, the `UIStackView` component tracks it's children's 'hidden' property and changes the constraints whenever the property changes.
You could put your slider and switch inside a `UIStackView` and set either one to visible or not.
I wouldn't do it that way though.
I'd construct two kind of cells, one with a `UISwitch`, and one with a `UISlider` and use a different cell based on the content.

Comment: Thank you iMoses for the feedback...  I originally had multiple custom Cells to handle the UISlider or UISwitch but I converted my app to use RxSwift and that framework doesn't handle multiple cells per table view (the way I've implemented it) so I'm kinda stuck with using a single cell.  Let me try the UIStackView (never used it before)...  I know it isn't elegant but if I works I've made worse design decisions :-)

Answer (score 0):

In Swift, The 'hidden' property is not a dynamic var. you can't observe it, but you can try to observe property setter.

details：http://simcai.com/2017/03/29/2017-03-29/

```
let view = UIView()

view.rx.methodInvoked(#selector(setter: showAllView.isHidden)).subscribe { (isHidden) in
    print("\(isHidden)")
}

view.isHidden = true
```